# How to center a Menu in Wordpress with style.css

Tags: css, wordpress

I have this piece of code in style.css

```
ul#secondary-menu {
    padding-left: 18px;
    width:960px;
}
```

how do I align this to be centered in page?

The page I am talking about is located here:
http://unacunatura.highacid.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your id in CSS

```
    ul#secondary-menu { 
    padding-left: 18px; 
    margin: auto;
    width: 300px;
   }
```

The width will define the width of the menu of course but the margin auto will align it in the center to its parent.

Given that it is a sub-menu you dont need to have it width 960px, just have the width the width of the content.

REF : http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp